# Rails wrong number of arguments error when generating migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run `bin/rails generate migration ClientsUsersXrefTable`

And I get this error:

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/
persistence.rb:138:in `destroy': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

I am on ruby 2.7.3p183 and rails 5.2.6. What am I missing? Here is the full trace.

```
Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. To suppress this message, set the GOOGLE_AUTH_SUPPRESS_CREDENTIALS_WARNINGS environment variable.
Note: Google::Cloud::Logging is disabled because the project ID could not be determined. Falling back to the default Rails logger.
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block in <class:Railtie> at /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:16)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using a deprecated processor interface Less::Rails::ImportProcessor.
Please update your processor interface:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block in <class:Railtie> at /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/less-rails-2.8.0/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:21)
Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. To suppress this message, set the GOOGLE_AUTH_SUPPRESS_CREDENTIALS_WARNINGS environment variable.
Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. To suppress this message, set the GOOGLE_AUTH_SUPPRESS_CREDENTIALS_WARNINGS environment variable.
Note: Google::Cloud::ErrorReporting is disabled because the project ID could not be determined.
Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. To suppress this message, set the GOOGLE_AUTH_SUPPRESS_CREDENTIALS_WARNINGS environment variable.
Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. To suppress this message, set the GOOGLE_AUTH_SUPPRESS_CREDENTIALS_WARNINGS environment variable.
Note: Google::Cloud::Trace is disabled because the project ID could not be determined.
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:138:in `destroy': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/user/projects/big-rain/app/models/user.rb:8:in `<class:User>'
        from /Users/user/projects/big-rain/app/models/user.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in `load_file'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:373:in `block in require_or_load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:316:in `get'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:346:in `new'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:346:in `add_mapping'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
        from /Users/user/projects/big-rain/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
        from /Users/user/projects/big-rain/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        from /Users/user/projects/big-rain/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:106:in `preload'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you already have a `ClientsUsersXref` table?

Comment: @dbugger no I have not created that table. I only have a Users model and a Clients model.

Comment: following the log i think your problem relates to `devise_for`, could you show your `devise` setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you run a Rails command, it will potentially set up a bunch of classes before doing the actual work, and unlike many other languages, in Ruby this setup is done by actual Ruby code (this is how DSLs work), and any broken code that runs during that time will prevent any commands from running.

It won't run any instance methods, but any broken class-level code will cause issues.

So the migration thing is just a red herring, presumably all your Rails commands are broken.

According to your stacktrace, `app/models/user.rb:8` (which you haven't provided), is getting run during initialisation. Models getting loaded during initialisation is quite common, but in this case that code is breaking.

Looking at the ActiveRecord source code (with `` less -N `bundle show activerecord`/lib/active_record/persistence.rb `` and looking at line 138), you seem to be calling the destroy class method (e.g. `User.destroy(1)`) but without parameters, like you do with the destroy instance method (e.g. `User.find(1).destroy`). So you should make sure you understand the difference between these two.

I'm not sure why you would be calling `User.destroy` outside of an instance method, but not having the relevant user model code I cannot say. Is there just a stray "destroy" by itself there?

Comment: Thanks, you were right. The models were already set with declarations for the Users and Clients models where `dependent: :destroy` was included. I removed those and set them to `has_and_belongs_to_many` and the migration ran. I appreciate the clear and instructive answer.

Comment: @analyticsPierce Right, that explains it, you must have had `destroy` instead of the `:destroy` that is required here.